# Set Up Cocos2d-X For Android On Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm new to cocos2d-X.I'm trying to set up cocos2d-x for android and I exactly followed below [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LI1IrRp_0w&index=2&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf4od_bOKN3WjAPr7snPXzoe) tutorial

I failed the steps in terminal with problem (python setup.py command result is not as expected).

For example when I begin to setup in terminal I get the following error.

```
 ->Please enter the path of NDK_ROOT (or press Enter to skip):/Users/apple/Documents/Development/Cosos2d-x/android-ndk-r9d 
->Error: "/Users/apple/Documents/Development/Cosos2d-x/android-ndk-r9d " is not a valid path of NDK_ROOT. Ignoring it.
->Check environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
->Search for environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT...
->ANDROID_SDK_ROOT not found

->Search for command android in system...
->Command android not found
```

The same above error happening for setup path ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANT_ROOT.

How can I fix the problem? Thanks for get me out.

I'm working on

- Mac OS 10.9.5
- android-ndk-r9d
- apache-ant-1.9.4
- cocos2d-x-3.3
- adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321

Comment: you wrote `Cosos2d`, did you mean `Cocos2d` with a `c`?

Comment: Question is from Cocos2d-X not Cocos2d with c

Comment: No, I mean you misspelled `Cocos`. You spelled it as `Cosos`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you copy the path to the terminal?

If so, try to delete the trailing whitespace, it will solve the problem.

Comment: How do i delete the trailing whitespace in mac's terminal.
NDK path is below here.Is anything wrong with this path?

/Users/apple/Documents/Development/Cosos2d-x/android-ndk-r9d

Comment: @StalinPusparaj Yes, the path is correct. I mean you must be sure, when you copy&paste this line when python script prompts you to input, the trailing whitespace is deleted.

Comment: @StalinPusparaj the problem is you misspelled `Cocos` in the path as `Cosos`. The trailing whitespace doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes I accepted but that Cosos2d-x is the name of the folder.I thing it doesn't make any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cocos script uses `os.path.join($your_path, $some_extra_file)`, so you have to add slash `/` at the end:

> /Users/apple/Documents/Development/Cosos2d-x/android-ndk-r9d/